# How to predefine <atomic> variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I'm doing homework on multithreading and have such template(paste part of it, which i should change):

```
...
class MeanCounter : public MeanCounterBase {
public:

...
};
...
```

I need to use `<atomic>` and predefine it in class.

What I did:

```
class MeanCounter : public MeanCounterBase {
public:
  std::atomic<unsigned> W;

  void MeanCounterBase () {
    W.store(0);
  }
private:
...
};
...
```

But it didn't work at all! Program compile without mistakes. However in all threads at start W is not equal 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the threading code, too?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What do you mean by predefine? Did you mean: "How to initialize an atomic variable"? Anyway, if it isn't initialized, then perhaps you forgot to call `MeanCounter::MeanCounterBase()` -function in all of the threads?

Comment: @Sean add code in question.

Comment: which university teaches C++11 ? I thought they barely teach C any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  void MeanCounterBase () {
    W.store(0);
  }
```

This is just a function inside `MeanCounter` class, and I doubt you ever call it. What you probably want, is a **constructor** for `MeanCounter`:

```
 MeanCounter() : W(0) { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you help me a little bit more?  Where should I put this constructor in my code?
When I am trying to put it inside MeanCounterBase, I get error: ‘MeanCounter::MeanCounter()’ is private.

Comment: @Acapello, you should put it in MeanCounter class.

Comment: @Acapello - If you don't know how to write a constructor you have no business writing multi-threaded code. You're in way over your head.

Comment: @Pete_Becker I do know how to write constructors. However, I have some mess in my head about  inheritance in C++. 
What about multithreading, I'll make every effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have meant `MeanCounter()` instead of `void MeanCounterBase ()` to declare a child class constructor that initializes the atomic value. I'm not very familiar with `atomic`s but I think you could initialize it in the initializer list instead of the constructor body.

Answer (score 0):

One way: Implement a constructor for mean counter that will set `W` to 0.
Another way: Use a default member initializer.